# How to set Flow layout for this scenario using UICollectionview?

Tags: ios, ipad, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I Wanted to design the UICollectionview both **portrait and landscape** mode.Here i am using **UICollectionViewFlowLayout**

I have entered my **view controller** code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    @IBOutlet var collectionObject: UICollectionView!
    var isOrientation = true
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: 90)
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        collectionObject.collectionViewLayout = layout
        collectionObject!.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.rotated), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
        collectionObject.delegate = self
        collectionObject.dataSource = self
        self .adjustContentInsets()
    }
    func rotated() {
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
            print("Landscape")
            // layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
            isOrientation = false
        } else {
            print("Portrait")
            //layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            isOrientation = true
            
        }
        collectionObject?.reloadData()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    //MARK: UICOLLECTIONVIEW DELEGATES AND DATASOURCE
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell  = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        cell.textLabel.text = String(indexPath.item)
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        var width :CGFloat = 0
        var height :CGFloat = 0
        if isOrientation == true {
            width = self.collectionObject!.frame.size.width / 2
            height = self.collectionObject!.frame.size.height / 2
        }else{
            width = self.collectionObject!.frame.size.height / 2
            height = self.collectionObject!.frame.size.height / 2
        }
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        }else if(indexPath.row == 1 || indexPath.row == 2){
            return CGSize(width: width / 2, height: height / 2)
        }else{
            var isLwidth :CGFloat = 0
            if isOrientation == true {
                isLwidth = self.collectionObject!.frame.size.width / 2 - 40
            }else{
                isLwidth = self.collectionObject!.frame.size.width / 2 - 3
            }
            return CGSize(width: isLwidth, height: 100)
        }
       
        //return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width-200, height: self.view.frame.size.height-250)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets{
         return UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
    }
    func adjustContentInsets() {
        let inset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height, 0, 0, 0)
        self.collectionObject.contentInset = inset
        self.collectionObject.scrollIndicatorInsets = inset
    }

   
}
```

My output not coming as excepted:

**Portrait Mode**

[image]

**Landscape Mode**

[image]

The output is entire wrong, i am doing wrong with **sizeForItemAt** delegate.How to make layout like below using **UICollectionview**?

**Actual Design:**
**Portrait**

[image]

**Landscape**

[image]

Here The collection view should not scroll both direction.The **array** count always **10** only.
I wanted to fit **CollectionViewCell** with in **view Bounds**
The bottom blue colour view is different **UIView**.
Or Is there any possible way to achieve this by **single control**?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: use delegate method to specify size for each cell at index - - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: i hope, i am using already sizeForItemAtIndexPath delegate

Comment: @karthikeyan: You can't achieve this using the normal flow layout. You need to create your own custom layout for this.

Comment: @MidhunMP are you talking about subclassing of UICollectionViewLayout?
If so, how can i make it? give me any sample or link

Comment: @karthikeyan: Check this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

Comment: They are returning image size and text content size, How can i modify to my requirement?

Comment: @MidhunMP I cannot find exact way to achieve this, can you help me with this?

Comment: @MidhunMP Thanks for comment... i did this by using https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout

Comment: @karthikeyan: Thanks for sharing the info. I wasn't aware of that library, thanks for sharing it :)